# Android NFC Card Emulation With Arduino MFRC522

Tags: android, arduino, nfc

I am developing an android application creating NFC card ID. I can get info from scanned NFC cards by phone. But I can't create them with my app. First, I tried to do that with [this method](https://proandroiddev.com/working-with-nfc-tags-on-android-c1e5af47a3db). Then, I realized need to have Tag object and tried to save it in different ways. Although it didn't work.

Secondly, I found [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce) from android documentations. Then, I tried to do with [HostNfcFService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/HostNfcFService) and [HostApduService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/HostApduService). To use them I created XML files and service classes like below;

nfcfservice.xml:

```
<!--HostNfcFService XML-->
<host-nfcf-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:description="NFCService">
<system-code-filter android:name="4000"/>
<nfcid2-filter android:name="02FE000000000000"/>
<t3tPmm-filter android:name="FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"/>
</host-nfcf-service>
<!--HostNfcFService XML-->
```

apduservice.xml:

```
<!--HostApduService XML-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:description="@string/servicedesc"
android:requireDeviceUnlock="false">
<aid-group android:description="@string/servicedesc"
    android:category="other">
    <aid-filter android:name="A0000002471001"/>
</aid-group>
</host-apdu-service>
<!--HostApduService XML-->
```

HostCardEmulatorService.java:

```
public class HostCardEmulatorService extends HostApduService {
    private static HostCardEmulatorService.ScannedByRemoteListener listener;

    @Override
    public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {
        byte[] response = null;
        if(listener != null)
        {
            response = listener.onScannedByRemote();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeactivated(int reason) {

    }

    public static void  setOnScannedByRemoteListener(HostCardEmulatorService.ScannedByRemoteListener listener)
    {
        HostCardEmulatorService.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface ScannedByRemoteListener
    {
        public byte[] onScannedByRemote();
    }
}
```

MyHostNfcFService.java:

```
public class MyHostNfcFService extends HostNfcFService {

    private static ScannedByRemoteListener listener;


    @Override
    public byte[] processNfcFPacket(byte[] commandPacket, Bundle extras) {
        byte[] response = null;
        if(listener != null)
        {
            response = listener.onScannedByRemote();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeactivated(int reason) {

    }

    public static void  setOnScannedByRemoteListener(ScannedByRemoteListener listener)
    {
        MyHostNfcFService.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface ScannedByRemoteListener
    {
        public byte[] onScannedByRemote();
    }
}
```

I define both ways in the manifest file like below;

```
<manifest>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true" />
...
<application>
...
<service
        android:name=".HostCardEmulatorService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
            android:resource="@xml/apduservice" />
    </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

It is the same for NfcFService. The only difference between them is "apdu" is renamed "nfcf". But still not working even both. I examine the following links to learn somethings.

https://medium.com/the-almanac/how-to-build-a-simple-smart-card-emulator-reader-for-android-7975fae4040f

[Android Host Card Emulation with Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570167/android-host-card-emulation-with-arduino)

[NFC - Help to exchange data between RC522 & Android HCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921686/nfc-help-to-exchange-data-between-rc522-android-hce)

But I didn't understand completely. So, I just did what I saw in there. I thought one of these services run its "processCommand" method when I try to scan my phone with a reader. But nothing happens.

Does anyone know how to do this? Does any special mean of names in XML files? Because I saw somewhere has 3 "aid-filter"s with different names. What am I missing?

NOTE1: I make my tests with Arduino Pro Mini and MFRC522 RFID reader. I tried to scan the NFC ID that was created from my app via MFRC522. Do I have to use another module for that problem?

NOTE2: I use listener in service classes to get NFC ID from activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the MFRC522 RFID reader is a very basic/old design and really only supports MIFARE type cards (which are the non standardised original card format). While Host Card emulation uses ISO/IEC 14443A (mostly) as a base it uses other higher level protocols to emulate a NFC Type 4 card which is not supported by that card reader.

If you look at an Arduino library for the reader https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid#troubleshooting

> My mobile phone doesn't recognize the MFRC522 or my MFRC522 can't read data from other MFRC522
> Card simulation is not supported.
> Communication with mobile phones is not supported.
> Peer to peer communication is not supported.

As the library suggest if you want more feature use a PN532 based modules instead.

If you look at an Arduino library for the PN532 https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/PN532#Features

> Communicate with android 4.0+(Lists of devices supported)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am gonna look at these.

Comment: I ordered PN532 and finally can try it today. It works for me. Thanks again for the answer.